# tensorflow cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found.？

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

my tensorflow-gpu is 2.0，cuda  10.0  cudnn  7.6 and when I use tf.test.is_gpu_available() it shows my gpu available
but when I run a cnn net with pycharm，it shows can't find the file cudart64_100.dll'，in fact, use anaconda to activate the env and when I import tensorflow it shows load successfully，then when I run with pycharm,it takes wrong

```
2019-11-23 15:42:51.795489: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
```

then there is also another err

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found.
```

I even don't know if these two err come from the same problem, help!

Comment: It seems to me that pycharm is not configured for your anaconda environment. Take a look at here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same errors running `cuda 10.2` and thought downgrading to `10.0` would help as `tf` looks for `cudart64_100.dll` and the lib folder only contains `cudart64_102.dll` but your post proves differently.

Comment: Update: surprisingly downgrading to `10.0` solved the problem. 

Don't forget to check you PATH to cuda if it is set to the accurate version.